# Prefix Routing not working after upgrade from 1.3 to 2.3.1

Tags: cakephp, upgrade

I have been able to run the non preix routes of my application, however, the admin prefix routes do not work and throw stack trace errors such as follows

```
Error: The view for UsersController::admin_home() was not found.
Error: Confirm you have created the file: C:\upgrade\app\View\Users\.ctp
```

Notice the only .ctp in the error and no file name? upon debugging the core I found /lib/cake/view/view.php :: render to have been invoked with null arguments. Is that normal?

Is there any place I can look further into to trace this?

Comment: Did you read the migration guide and/or docs? On how prefixes work in 2.x? http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the url you are calling the action with?

As stated in the documentation you need to use the new 2.x syntax to enable prefixes:

```
Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin', ...));
```

This will be done in your core.php

Also you need to assert that you load your default routes in your routes.php, as 2.x will not automatically do that anymore:

```
require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';
```